# Images in XAML ResourceDictionary disappear on ToolBar when Menu opens

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I have started to move various common `Image`s into a `ResourceDictionary` and noticed an odd behavior in my WPF application. If the `Image` is used in a `MenuItem` and in a `Button` on a `ToolBar`, when I open the `Menu` the image disappears on the `Button`.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Image x:Key="NewImage"
           Source="/SomeApplication;component/Resources/NewDocumentHS.png"
           Stretch="None"/>
    <!-- ... -->
```

Relevant XAML from the `Window`:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="_File">
        <MenuItem Header="_New"
                  Command="{Binding NewCommand}"
                  Icon="{DynamicResource NewImage}" />
<!-- ... -->
<ToolBarTray>
    <ToolBar>
        <Button Command="{Binding NewCommand}"
                Content="{DynamicResource NewImage}" />
```

I assume this is a caveat of resources in a `ResourceDictionary`, but I am unable to discover the appropriate fix for this. Behavior occurs with both `StaticResource` and `DynamicResource`. It also doesn't appear to be affected by if the `ResourceDictionary` stands on its own or if it is merged with others. No other resource shares that key either.

**Edit**: Additionally, adding `PresentationOptions:Freeze="True"` to the images did not change the situation.

Comment: This sounds eerily similar to my experience with Path styles in Silverlight 4! The runtime only renders the first instance of the resource applied, after that just emptiness where the shape (in my case vector icons) should be :( I haven't found any workarounds either...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Image class is a visual, so it can only appear in the visual tree in one location. Therefore, you cannot share it among multiple MenuItems/Buttons/etc.

You can however share the ImageSource (i.e. Image.Source) value.

In WPF, I believe you can use [x:Shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx)="False" to force WPF to create a new instance for each request though.

Comment: Now that you mention its a `Visual` the behavior seems entirely obvious! The `x:Shared` bit was entirely non-obvious. Working well, many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an Image control in multiple places, it can only be appear in the Visual Tree at one place, so if the call to the resource is made the image is being snatched from the previous owner.

**Edit:** `x:Shared="False"` Is obviously a better solution than all of my suggestions below, i wonder why such an important property does not show up in the Intellisense -_-

---

This behaviour is a bit of a pain, i normally use to predefine a `IconStyle` and the `BitmapImages` for the Source of the images but create new Images for every `MenuItem` where i might need it.

You can also create a DataTemplate for your Icon:

Resources:

```
    <Style x:Key="IconImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="16"/>
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Icon_Close_Template">
        <Image Style="{StaticResource IconImageStyle}"
               Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/Close.ico"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Usage:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="File">
        <MenuItem Header="Close">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Icon_Close_Template}"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Close">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Icon_Close_Template}"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Since templates are created via factories this will work, still significantly inflates the XAML though...

To get around this you could for example write a markup extension, this one is very simple and only copies the values of the `Source` and `Style` properties, you could also use reflection or other means to create a complete copy:

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object))]
public class IconExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private Image icon;
    public Image Icon
    {
        get { return icon; }
        set { icon = value; }
    }

    public IconExtension() { }
    public IconExtension(Image icon)
    {
        Icon = icon;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Icon == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Icon");
        return new Image() { Source = Icon.Source, Style = Icon.Style };
    }
}
```

Can be used like this:

```
<Style x:Key="IconImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="16"/>
</Style>
<Image x:Key="Icon_Close"  Style="{StaticResource IconImageStyle}" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/Close.ico"/>
<!-- ... -->
<MenuItem Header="File">
    <MenuItem Header="Close" Icon="{m:Icon {StaticResource Icon_Close}}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Close" Icon="{m:Icon {StaticResource Icon_Close}}"/>
</MenuItem>
```